# SQL Server MDF Files Split guidelines

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database, database-performance

Are there any specific guidelines to split up a single MDF file into multiple files for a single database. An example of a scheme that I can think of is splitting it so that one NDF file contains just indexes and another just the tables which take Insert operations, another one that has large tables etc, so the scheme would look something like:

1. MDF containing smaller tables
2. NDF containing indexes
3. NDF containing larger tables
4. NDF containing tables optimized for insert operations

Also, all these files would be on separate drives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are guidelines on what you can and can't do, but how to implement it in your environment depends on your architecture.  Splitting things up can help, but it's not always a good idea.  You need to know your I/O architecture and how SQL Server uses it so that you can plan appropriately.

Have a look through these:

- [**Paul Randal's blog**](http://sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/)
- [**Files and Filegroups Architecture (MSDN)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179316.aspx)
- [**SQL Server Filegroups**](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/tips/filegroups_p1.aspx)
- [**SQL Server Reference Guide - Files and Filegroups**](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=sqlserver&seqNum=42)